# Hourly alert (chime) in Gear S3

Tags: tizen

How to make a hourly alert in a native watchface app for Gear S3?
Any code samples?

Comment: Did you add below lines in to tizen-manifest.xml file of the watchface app?
<privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm.get</privilege>
<privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm.set</privilege>

Comment: Yes I did.
These lines are in the tizen-manifest.xml of the watchface app.

Comment: Edit question with the code in manifest file. I'm not getting such error. I guess you missed any of the steps.

Comment: I added two manifest files - for the application and for the service.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your first answer was correct!
I used the version of Tizen API 3.0, but correctly was API 2.3.
The second answer will also be useful to keep in mind for the future.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped!

Comment: One more question. Perhaps it will be more correct to use command  **ret = app_control_destroy(app_control)**  at the end of the function **init_alert()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using Alarm API in this purpose. Follow the steps below:

1. At first create a Watch Application and a Service Application. Package both of the apps and build. Go through [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/application-development-process#develop) to do the packaging.
2. Now use the below code snippet in the watchface app to trigger the alert after a specific time which is 1hr in your case.

   ```
   bool init_alert(){
   int ret;
   int DELAY = 3;
   int REMIND = 3600; //alert after every 1hr.
   int alarm_id;

   app_control_h app_control = NULL;
   ret = app_control_create(&app_control);
   ret = app_control_set_operation(app_control, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_DEFAULT);
   ret = app_control_set_app_id(app_control, "Service_App_ID");
   ret = alarm_schedule_after_delay(app_control, DELAY, REMIND, &alarm_id);

   return true;}
   ```

   Use below privileges in watchface app manifest file:

   http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm.get

   http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm.set
3. Now in service_app_control() function of the service app, create an alert using the below code:

   ```
   void service_app_control(app_control_h app_control, void *data){

   dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Hourly Alert Here");
   notification = notification_create(NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NOTI);
   int ret =0;
   ret = notification_set_text(notification, NOTIFICATION_TEXT_TYPE_TITLE, "Hourly Alert!!",
                               NULL, NOTIFICATION_VARIABLE_TYPE_NONE);
   ret = notification_post(notification);
   notification_free(notification);
   return;}
   ```

Use below privilege in service app manifest file:

```
http://tizen.org/privilege/notification
```

To know in details go through [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.tutorials/html/native/app_framework/alarm_tutorial_n.htm).

**Edit: 1**
You may find the reason of this problem into [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__ALARM__MODULE.html#ga695ffe84e14f626f3929bf844b454089). Please go through **remarks** and **see also** section. I've posted the answer for version 2.3.2 previously. That's why I wasn't getting any error.
Please follow the way below. It works for version 3.0 in my case.

**Step 1:** Take a counter, at first set it to 0 and increment it every time the clock gives 0 for seconds like this:

```
watch_time_get_second(watch_time, &second);
if(second == 0) count++;
```

**Step 2:** Now, check the counter value if it equals to your required value e.g. if you want an alert after every 3 minutes interval then you may check whether it equals to 3 and after that create a notification like this:

```
if(count == 3){
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Hourly Alert");
            notification = notification_create(NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NOTI);

            int ret =0;
            ret = notification_set_text(notification, NOTIFICATION_TEXT_TYPE_TITLE, "Hourly Alert!!",
                    NULL, NOTIFICATION_VARIABLE_TYPE_NONE);
            ret = notification_post(notification);
            notification_free(notification);
            count = 0;
        }
```

At the end, set the counter to 0, to get ready to count for the next interval. Find the full code structure below for a good understanding:

```
#include <notification.h>
static notification_h notification = NULL;
int count = 0;


static void
update_watch(appdata_s *ad, watch_time_h watch_time, int ambient)
{
    char watch_text[TEXT_BUF_SIZE];
    int hour24, minute, second;

    if (watch_time == NULL)
        return;

    watch_time_get_hour24(watch_time, &hour24);
    watch_time_get_minute(watch_time, &minute);
    watch_time_get_second(watch_time, &second);

    if (!ambient) {
        if(second == 0) count++;

        if(count == 3){
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Hourly Alert");
            notification = notification_create(NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NOTI);

            int ret =0;
            ret = notification_set_text(notification, NOTIFICATION_TEXT_TYPE_TITLE, "Hourly Alert!!",
                    NULL, NOTIFICATION_VARIABLE_TYPE_NONE);
            ret = notification_post(notification);
            notification_free(notification);
            count = 0;
        }
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "cnt = %d", count);
        snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>Hello<br/>%02d:%02d:%02d</align>",
                hour24, minute, second);
    } else {
        snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>Hello Watch<br/>%02d:%02d</align>",
                hour24, minute);
    }

    elm_object_text_set(ad->label, watch_text);
}
```

**N.B: Don't forget to add privilege for notification.**

Comment: Thank you!
But **alarm_schedule_after_delay()** return **ALARM_ERROR_NOT_PERMITTED_APP**, that means that - _If app_control is not UI application, ALARM_ERROR_NOT_PERMITTED_APP returned._ ([description](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__ALARM__MODULE.html#ga83e440e25f14588b9bf2a6193cf6653c)).  How to fix it?

Comment: From the guide, you needs to use a service app for app_control of alarm_schedule_after_delay.